# ruby on rails routing for non resource action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails. I already have these routes

```
  namespace :swimming do resources :classschedules    end
```

Now I added a new action to this controller

```
class Swimming::ClassschedulesController < ApplicationController

  def date 
    @date = params[0]
  end
end
```

How do I add a route for this new action ?

I would like to call like swimming/classschedules/date/2013-03-07 . It would be a single element and 2013-03-07 is parameter I would like to use in this action.

Comment: As answered by @dimuch, you can add `:collection` instead of `:member` for the route you specified. But what is the exact use case? Do you want date for a particular **classschedule** or for all **classschedules**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want an url like `/swimming/classcehdules/date/2012-12-03` to match try:

```
namespace :swimming do
  resources :classschedules do
    get 'date/:date', :action => 'date', :as => :date, :on => :collection,
                      :constraints => { :date => /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/ }
  end 
end
```

The additional `:constraint` is to ensure that the `:date` param is in the expected form. In your action you can fetch the date as:

```
def date
   @date = params[:date] # => "2012-12-03"
end
```

Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more informations regarding routing.

Comment: lwe, you need to tell it where to put the get.  Throw the get line inside of a `collection do .... end` block.

Comment: aye, added :on => :collection

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace :swimming do 
  resources :classschedules do
    get 'date', :on => :member # or collection
  end
end
```

More info in [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Swimming::ClassschedulesController#show

Couldn't find Swimming::Classschedule with id=date

Comment: Do you need to call this method on a single element (`swimming/classschedules/1/date`) or on the collection (`swimming/classschedules/date`) ?

Comment: I would like to call like swimming/classschedules/date/2013-03-07 . It would be a single element  and 2013-03-07 is parameter I would like to use in this action

Comment: This answer would work, just got to change `:member` to `:collection`.